# Fitting Simultaneous Equations involving arbitrary function

Tags: equation-solving, fitting

```
n = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3}
```

I guessed a function of n.  This function is subject to change, so please suggested a different function if required (I can then reproduce "fitFEqnToZero" list, which is written below further down and edit the post).

```
fC[x_] := a^b*Log[c*x^d] + e
```

a,b,c,d, and e are arbitrary variables.  So please reduce or increase the number of these.

```
fcForFit = fC /@ n

    {e + a^b Log[c], e + a^b Log[2^d c], e + a^b Log[3^d c], 
 e + a^b Log[4^d c], e + a^b Log[5^d c], e + a^b Log[4^d c], 
 e + a^b Log[4^d c], e + a^b Log[4^d c], e + a^b Log[4^d c], 
 e + a^b Log[4^d c], e + a^b Log[4^d c], e + a^b Log[4^d c], 
 e + a^b Log[3^d c], e + a^b Log[3^d c], e + a^b Log[4^d c], 
 e + a^b Log[2^d c], e + a^b Log[3^d c]}
```

I used fcForFit to construct the following list of equations (if you have a different function, I can construct again).

```
    fitFEqnToZero = {-603 + 13.36 qB (e + a^b Log[c]), -940 + 
  22 qB (e + a^b Log[2^d c]), -1401+ 
  22 qB (e + a^b Log[3^d c]) + 
  13 qT (e + a^b Log[3^d c]), -1378 + 
  22 qB (e + a^b Log[4^d c]) + 
  22 qT (e + a^b Log[4^d c]), -1431 + 
  33 qB (e + a^b Log[5^d c]) + 
  22 qT (e + a^b Log[5^d c]), -1649 + 
  11 qB (e + a^b Log[4^d c]) + 
  33 qT (e + a^b Log[4^d c]), -1907 + 
  11 qB (e + a^b Log[4^d c]) + 
  33 qT (e + a^b Log[4^d c]), -1718 + 
  11 qB (e + a^b Log[4^d c]) + 
  33 qT (e + a^b Log[4^d c]), -1718 + 
  11 qB (e + a^b Log[4^d c]) + 
  33 qT (e + a^b Log[4^d c]), -1770 + 
  11 qB (e + a^b Log[4^d c]) + 
  33 qT (e + a^b Log[4^d c]), -1587 + 
  11 qB (e + a^b Log[4^d c]) + 
  33 qT (e + a^b Log[4^d c]), -1640 + 
  11 qB (e + a^b Log[4^d c]) + 
  33 qT (e + a^b Log[4^d c]), -1339 + 
  13 qB (e + a^b Log[3^d c]) + 
  22 qT (e + a^b Log[3^d c]), -1297 + 
  22 qB (e + a^b Log[3^d c]) + 
  11 qT (e + a^b Log[3^d c]), -1501 + 
  19 qB (e + a^b Log[4^d c]) + 
  20 qT (e + a^b Log[4^d c]), -1574 + 
  8 qB (e + a^b Log[2^d c]) + 
  13 qT (e + a^b Log[2^d c]), -1297 + 
  33 qT (e + a^b Log[3^d c])}
```

Now I want to set `fitFEqnToZero[[1]], fitFEqnToZero[[2]]...fitFEqnToZero[[Length[fitFEqnToZero]]]...`  all to zero and fit simultaneously for the following variables

```
{qB, a, b, c, d,  e, qT}
```

with the following constraints

```
fcoil[1] == 1 && qB <= 2000 && qT <= 2000 && fcoil[2] <= 1 && 
  fcoil[3] <= 1 && fcoil[4] <= 1 && 
  fcoil[5] <= 1},
```

How can I do this?  Is Nsolve, NMinimize or other the most appropriate?

If I use NMinimize should I fit to Total[fitFEqnToZero] == 0? Is this effective the same or could this result in some of the elements in list fitFEqnToZero  being non-zero?

Comment: if you have seventeen equations and seven variables you're unlikely to get a solution. Do you have any reason to expect that there will be one?

Comment: How about applying NMinimize to Total[fitFEqnToZero] == 0.  And obtain the nearest solution. Would this minimize the sum of squared errors of all of the points relative to the solution? How would I ensure NMinimize is fitting to zero and not a negative number?

Comment: You could square your equations: `NMinimize[fitFEqnToZero^2]`. Or more generally, `NMinimize[ d[ fitFEqnToZero, 0] ]`, where `d` is some approptiately chosen metric.

Comment: Taking the absolute value seems to minimise to zero. Without Abs it gives a largish negative number, which is what I don't want. I'll try some different functions with this.  NMinimize[{Abs[fitFloodEqnToZeroLongEqn]....

Comment: The nMinimize of Total[fitFEqnToZero] == 0 is zero. However each element of fitFEqnToZero is far from zero.  Do I need to add constraint for each element of list fitFEqnToZero?